# Brand Positioning on Website

Tags: html, css

I had a look at this website: http://www.rutherfordcapital.co.za/

How do they position their logo in the center so that the top part is slightly higher than the black navbar and the low part of the logo extending into the image?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: `How do they position their logo` simply F12 and see in element/style what the do

Comment: little tip - right click and choose inspect element, you can see all the styles applied to it - in this case the link has been positioned absolutely

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using negative margins on the logo, something like this:

```
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: -15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

For that use `margin` for getting the desire position of the image and use `z-index: 1;` for making logo appear at the front.
For detail

- right click on the logo
- Then select inspect element
- you can then view html code and css of that part

Answer (score -1):

Keeping the `z-index` of the logo higher than the image and navbar and using absolute positioning this can be done.